# About thread switching, hopping and thread reuse in TPL with respect to AsyncLocal

Tags: .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, executioncontext

When using async/await in TPL, will it reuse idle threads and in theory invoke callbacks on other threads than used initially?

About AsyncLocal in this context, will it pass its value around to match the flow or could I end up with a value from another reused thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async-await will pick a random thread from the thread-pool, unless there is a [SynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/february/msdn-magazine-parallel-computing-it-s-all-about-the-synchronizationcontext), which can force TPL to continue on the same thread.

The idea of `AsyncLocal` is to persist a value across threads.  It is `ThreadLocal` that is thread-specific.

Comment: So the value in AsyncLocal will stay the same even when returning to a random thread? No chance the value will be seen by another flow?

Comment: That is the idea.